# How to launch a url in a text box on chrome? c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I am currently working on a school project using C# which is to develop a basic program of my choice.  Currently I'm faced with the problem of trying to implement a function where a URL is imputed into a textbox and a button would open that url in a web browser.

I've been searching for a solution to this problem but haven't found any luck as of yet so I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided enough information. Lets assume you have ASP.NET MVC app.

UI

[image]

View
[image]

Controller
[image]